# Check if a number is prime using recursion

Tags: recursion, primes

This is a recursive check if this is a prime number -- is it correct?

```
public static boolean isPrimeRecursive (int n,int i){//i eqoual to n
    if (n <= 1) {  
       return false;  
    }if (i==1){
        return false;
    }if(n%i==0){
        return false;
    }

   return isPrimeRecursive(n,i--);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't burden your user with that mysterious second argument but rather present a different method of just one argument, that first deals with numbers less than 2 and even numbers, and then calls into your recursive method with the proper arguments:

```
private static boolean isPrimeRecursive(int n, int i) {

    if (i * i > n) {
        return true;
    }

    if (n % i == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return isPrimeRecursive(n, i + 2);
}

public static boolean isPrime(int n) {

    if (n <= 2 || n % 2 == 0) {
        return (n == 2);
    }

    return isPrimeRecursive(n, 3);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(isPrime(Integer.parseInt(args[0])));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With your code, you should start of `i` with a value of `n-1` since `n % n` is always true of prime numbers.

Then in your condition (`if (i == 1) { ... }`, should return true because if the method reaches to `1`, then it fulfills all other conditions.

Finally in your return statement `return isPrimeRecursive(n, i++);`, it is better to use `++i` since `i++` will increment after the execution of the function with the value of `i`.

```
public static boolean isPrimeRecursive (int n,int i){
    if (n <= 1) {  
       return false;  
    }

    if (i == 1) {
        return true;
    }

    if(n % i == 0){
        return false;
    }

   return isPrimeRecursive(n, --i);
}
```

In your main function, you will then use:

```
int n = 17;

System.out.println(isPrimeRecursive(n, n-1);
```

Another way of doing it is to always start `i` with a value of `2` and increment it's value. From there.

```
public static boolean isPrimeRecursive (int n, int i) {
    if (n <= 2) {  
       return (n == 2) ? true : false;  
    }

    if (i >= n) {
        return true;
    }

    if (n % i == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return isPrimeRecursive(n, ++i);
}
```

Then you simple do:

```
int n = 17;

System.out.println(isPrimeRecursive(n, 2);
```